# CloudQueue.BeginAddMessage in logger implementation

Tags: .net, performance, azure, asynchronous, azure-storage

I'm thinking about performance aspect of using `CloudQueue.BeginAddMessage` method for logging purpose. Each call to `logger.LogMessage` will result in sending a message to Azure queue. I know that each call to `BeginAddMessage` will send a POST request. Waiting for it to complete is not an option because my goal is to make `logger.LogMessage` method as fast as possible. That's why I plan to only fire the operation and forget (if the request fails it's not so critical).

How time-consuming is calling `CloudQueue.BeginAddMessage`?

Does it perform HTTP request initialization (like building HTTP body, opening connection, etc) before returninig?

If yes then I'll have to move this initialization to some other thread by wrapping it in asynchronous call, like `Task.Run(() => CloudQueue.BeginAddMessage())`.

Are there better options?

Comment: You do realize that creating a lot of threads using Task.Run might create more overhead than the http request initialization, if that happens?

Comment: Yes, that's one of my concerns. Still not sure what is better until I know how the BeginAddMessage works

Comment: You can look at the source code to see how it is implemented: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/Lib/ClassLibraryCommon/Queue/CloudQueue.cs.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my suggestion: define a memory queue in your program, and what logger.LogMessage() does is just to add a new message to the memory queue. Besides, start a dedicated background thread to consume the memory queue and upload the log messages into Azure Queue. You can even have a Semaphore for this dedicated thread to upload log messages in a concurrency which can be controlled by you.